# Displaying records horizontally in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM   aa_tbl 
       LEFT JOIN bb_tbl 
              ON ( bb_uid = aa_source 
                   AND bb_date = $date 
                    OR bb_month = $month 
                       AND bb_year = $year ) 
WHERE  bb_lvl = 'User'
```

And it displays the data like this, which works fine.

[image: View Image]

But I want it to display like this.

[image: View Image]

Is there something that I need to adjust on my query to display the items horizontally without adding another row.

**Note:**
user1 is on **AA_tbl** table and the number(periods) is on **BB_tbl** table.

Answer (score 0):

Try GROUP BY clause in the User Column.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response I tried GROUP BY although it displays only one user it only displays 1 highlighted box the other highlighted boxes are hidden.if there is a way i could merge the 3 into 1 row

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT aa_tbl.*, bb_tbl.bb_date, bb_tbl.bb_month, bb_tbl.bb_year
FROM aa_tbl JOIN bb_tbl ON aa_tbl.source = bb_uid
WHERE (bb_date = $date AND bb_month = $month  AND bb_year = $year)
     AND bb_lvl = 'User'
GROUP BY bb_tbl.id  // id of bb_tbl here
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried your code but it still shows the same. Additional Info... the numbers(period) is created using do... while statement, I'm not sure if using "do...while" might affect my query.

Comment: hmmm try to replace OR with AND on "bb_date = $date OR bb_month"

Comment: Tried it but still the same